# AngularJS - Directives in a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to find the best approach for dynamically creating the sub-contents of an element created using a directive.

To give a simple example, say I have directive that say creates a basic `div` child element.

```
<div mydirective></div>
```

results in

```
<div mydirective><div></div></div>
```

The directive might look something like:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',           
        template:   '<div></div>'
    }
})
```

Then say I wanted to create an "extension" to this directive that makes the inner `div` blue.  Because I don't know what future extensions I'll need I don't want to switch the template or bind any specific attributes.

I don't know what of these are possible, or what the normal approach is... but can you

1) Add an additional directive to the parent element (bit like css) i.e.

```
<div mydirective mybluedirective></div>
```

Where the `mybluedirective` looks for the inner div and manipulates it?

or

2) Can you include directive dynamically in the template, e.g.

`<div mydirective subdirective="mybluedirective"></div>`

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',           
        template:   '<div [[[THE SUBDIRECTIVE PROPERTY FROM SCOPE??]]></div>'
    }
})
```

Is there a way you can intercept pre-compile to inject the directive?

a third option as I've ready is to use a factory and inherited classes to do the work for the directive, but that seems an overkill.

I'm guessing there is an easy way I don't know about, any advice appreciated

EDIT:

I think what I'm trying to do is dynamically modify the template to use another directive before it's compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1 - Dynamically Modifying the Template

If you want to dynamically modify a template before compilation, you can use the template function:

HTML:

```
<div mydirective subdirective="mybluedirective"></div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',           
        template:   function(element, attr) { 
             return '<div ' + attr.subdirective + '></div>'
        }
    }
})
```

#### Option 2 - Programmatic Access to Template

Alternatively, you could expose an API from `mydirective` that `mybluedirective` could use. This solution requires mydirective to delay compilation (because the template will be compiled manually), and more thought as to how `mydirective` is designed and intended to be extended:

**HTML**

```
<div mydirective mybluedirective></div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('mydirective', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',           
        template:   '<div></div>',
        // we want a child scope so that we don't pollute the parent scope
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var attrs = {};
            // expose an API to add attributes dynamically
            this.addAttr = function(attr, value) {
                attrs[attr] = value;
            }
            $scope.attrs = attrs;
        },
        compile: function(element, attr) {
            // save the template
            var template = element.find('div');

            // empty the contents so it is not compiled (we're manually compiling during link)
            element.empty();

            return function(scope, element, attr) {
                // add the attributes to the template
                angular.forEach($scope.attrs, function(value, key) {
                    template.addAttr(key, value);
                }
                // add the template to the DOM
                element.append(template);

                // link the template to scope
                $compile(template)(scope);
            }

        }

    }
})
.directive('mybluedirective', function() {
     return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'mydirective',
          link: function(scope, element, attr, mydirectiveController) {
               mydirectiveController.addAttr('ng-class','blue');
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: great, this is the solution to 2) of my question

Comment: both good answers, but the directive one is cleaner for me. upvoted, but accepted the other one

Comment: thanks. that's what i'm trying to do "2)". When the mydirective compiles then, it would include any template defined in 'mybluedirective' correct?  Also, is there a common way of communicating between the directives? presumably they'd need to share a controller?

Comment: and does the `require` property negate the need for priority?

Comment: Using the 'require' is a common way for directives to communicate. The other way is through attributes.  As to your second question, it depends - priority is not strictly needed for this solution to work. But you may want to specify priority to ensure the order in which the directives are applied.

Comment: thanks,what about both directives requesting a template?

Comment: The one that has the lower priority will win the template battle. If both have the same priority, then the order is undefined. Thinking about it again, I think priority is necessary to ensure order.

Comment: From `mybluedirective` - how would i bind values to the controller of the directive (mybluedirective) when it's compiled in the other directive (mydirective) - is there a way of referencing a specific controller?

Comment: It would be wierd, but you could pass a different scope (from the other directive) into your API function, and then compile/link manually against the other scope.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I think that would work, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I use an ng-class to bind to an exposed variable inside the directive.  You'd also need to add a scope, and if you want to set a default, then a controller or link function.

Here is a quick sample:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',           
        // add the ng-class to the template.  It binds to options.someClass
        template:   '<div ng-class="options.someClass"></div>',
        // give the directive its own Scope with an input object named options
        scope: {
            options : "="
        },  
        // Give the directive a controller
        controller: function($scope) {
            //  This is an init function to default the input objects 
             this.onInit = function(){
                   //  If the options object does not exist; create it 
                    if(!$scope.options){
                        $scope.options = {};
                    }
                   //  If our custom someClass variable doesn't exist; then give it a default value
                    if(!$scope.options.someClass){
                        $scope.options.someClass= "defaultClass";
                    }            }
             // call the onInit() function to set up the defaults
             onInit();
        }
    }
})
```

Then I also provide a CSS as part of the directive containing the default styles.  You can put this in practice relatively easily.  In your controller create our options object:

```
myDirectiveOptions = {
   someClass = 'myCustomClass';
}
```

In your view, do this:

```
<div mydirective options="myDirectiveOptions"></div>
```

I have found this to be simple, yet very powerful.

---

Using this approach; to change the directive--ng-class--dynamically; you merely have to update the options object.  Somewhere in your controller, you can do:

```
myDirectiveOptions.someClass = 'someOtherCustomClass';
```

The ng-class inside of myDirective should pick it up automatically thanks to the magic of Angular binding.  This change does not have to be inside myDirective's controller.

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but I'm looking to switch the directive (in this case ng-class) dynamically.

Comment: @sambomartin I updated my answer; in this case you just need to change `myDirectiveOptions.someClass` and myDirective should pick up the changes automagically.  I do this very same thing in one of my apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second directive that looks for the result of the first one. Just make sure that "mybluedirective" has higher priority than "mydirective".

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XHJC2/

```
angular.module("demo", []).
    controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope) {

    }).
    directive('mybluedirective', function () {
        return {
            priority: 4000,
            restrict: 'A',           
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                elem.find('div').html('modified!');
            }
        };
    }).
    directive('mydirective', function() {
        return {
            priority: 40,
            restrict: 'A',           
            template:   '<div>TEST</div>'
        };
    });
```

Here is doc about "priority" in directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-

Comment: great, and this is the solution to 1) of my question

Comment: is there a way of using a template for this directive too? i'm not sure how that would work, but rather than replace the html, apply a directive specific template

Comment: I don't understand where would the other template be rendered since the goal is to modify the markup and not completely replace it. You can manually compile the template by injecting $compile in the directive and calling $compile('<div>my template {{bindMe}}</div>')(scope). The result of this function can be inserted in an element of your choice (instead of replacing everything).